# BlackBerry-Storing images in PersistentStore

Tags: image, blackberry, persistent-storage

Can i store images in PersistentStore? is it advisable? What is your experience?
I want to store images what is better file system or persistentstore? what are its pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can i store images in PersistentStore?

Yes this is possible.  You can use the Bitmap.getARGB method to obtain a byte array of the Bitmap.  Then store its contents in a ByteVector. 
[can bitmap be saved to persistent store?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/can-bitmap-be-saved-to-persistent-store/td-p/19272)

> What is your experience?

1. From file system user can delete files.
2. file system read/write is slower than persistence store.

Comment: is there any way to manage file access?i mean is there any way to prevent others to access files created by our application?

Comment: using `enableDRMForwardLock()` you can restrict user to forward file to another device. 
using `setHidden(true)` you can hide file.
you can also encrypt the file.
But still AFAIK you can't restrict user from deletion of your file.